# Count IF with Date and Time in single Cell (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that lists the date and time of an event in the same cell (`mm/dd/yy h:mm`). I need to find a way to count how many events took place between a certain time range in a Hourly Basis.

I could sum if the cell contains dates only however the cell contains with date which i am unable to get the values.

[image]

Basically, all datas are in `cell A`, so i need to count how many events happened at 6am, 7am , and so on... as on hourly basis.

Comment: Try COUNTIFS. For date 23rd and time between 6am and 7am, Add 2 conditions, first where date column is greater than 6am and second condition on same date column with date less than 7am

Answer (score 3):

Your column `A` looks like properly formatted date & time value, so its manipulation is easy. If it's not (ie, not date but text) you should first convert it to date value.

```
=DATE(MID(A2,7,4), MID(A2,4,2), LEFT(A2,2)) + TIME(MID(A2,12,2), MID(A2,15,2), RIGHT(A2,2))
```

Say this was `C2`. Now that column `C` is date & time, set `$D$2` to date to query(ex `2017-03-26`), `E2` to start time(ex `6:00`), and `F2` to end time(ex `7:00`), then you can count events from 6:00 to 7:00 like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&($D$2+E2), C:C,"<"&($D$2+F2))
```

Sample file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ctmpj4bhyx9j3w/43166877.xlsx?dl=0) and its screenshot is below.

[image]

Comment: hi i tried to do the sample below but got zero results. (i cant see my screenshot i just posted.  :')  )

Comment: Well then A:A seems to be text values not date+time values... If so, you first re-format them to data+time values. If you attach (using Dropbox, etc) your Excel file in your question body, I'll look for it.

Comment: As I suspected, A:A was text. You can a proper date&time of A2 by `=DATE(MID(A2,7,4), MID(A2,4,2), LEFT(A2,2)) + TIME(MID(A2,12,2), MID(A2,15,2), RIGHT(A2,2))`. I updated the answer.

Comment: hmmm thats nice, however how to i do this in all column A because all dates are there. nearly thousand entries so i have to convert each and every rows?

Comment: Just add one column (in my answer, `C`) and use it instead of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If the times spanned different dates and you still wanted to see how many events happened in a particular hour of the day, you would need an array-type formula, e.g. if the start time in hours (entered as a normal number) is in C2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR($A$2:$A$10)=C2))
```

or if the start hour is entered as a time

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR($A$2:$A$10)=HOUR(C2)))
```